# want to implement a python code with pseudocode given

Tags: python

I have a pseudocode and I am required to implement a python code. 
Here is my pseudocode

```
find_bully_1(A):
    for student in class:
        if student is afraid of no one:
            candidate = student

    if no such candidate found:
        return None

    if everyone is afraid of candidate:
        return candidate as bully
    else:
        return None
```

Below is what I have done, but there are bugs and it just could not output something. I was not really familiar with python though

```
def find_bully_1(A):

    n = len(A)
    candidate = 0
    bully = 0
    a = []

    for i in range(n):
        count = 0
        for j in range(n):
            if A[i][j] == 0:
                count = count + 1
        if count == n:
            candidate += 1
            a = [a,i]

    count_scare = 0

    for k in [a]:
        count_scare = 0
        for g in range(n):
            if (zip(*A))[k][g] == 1:
                count_scare += 1
                if count_scare == n-candidate:
                    bully += 1

    return bully


x = [[1,1,1,1],
     [0,0,0,1],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: What are the bugs? What is your input? What is your output?

Comment: Can you explain a little more about your input data? I'm guessing x is the input and a 1 indicates scared and 0 not scared? So does each row represent a person? Which row is the bully?

Comment: Your input data are not clear. Or is the bully afraid of himself?

Comment: The input will be a matrix with 1 and 0. If x[i][j] == 1 means student i is afraid of student j. A bully is someone that do no afraid of anyone but everyone else if afraid of him. The algorithm above need to output the number of bullies in the class.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to read about Python and follow a [few tutorials](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/). Although, I love Python and would like to demonstrate how easy and readable it can be. The following code reads almost as pseudo-code.

```
find_bully_in(my_class):
    for student, afraid in enumerate(my_class):
        if not any(afraid):
            candidate = student
        else:
            continue

        other_students = [student for student, _ in enumerate(my_class) if student != candidate]

        if all([afraid_of[candidate] for afraid_of in other_students]):
            return candidate
    else:
        return None
```

I don't think any other language can beat the readability capabilities that Python can achieve.

On the other hand, it does not mean you cannot achieve unreadable one-liners:

```
find_bully_in(cls):
    return next(filter(lambda s: not any(s[1]) and list(zip(*cls))[s[0]].count(1) == len(cls) - 1, enumerate(cls)), None)
```